# Calculate mean of a range of XML Elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, range, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate the mean of a range of XML elements in PHP, but haven't found any solution yet.

Here are the XML elements.

```
<root>
    <quoteDay>
      <date>2018-02-26</date>
      <close>1586,96</close>
    </quoteDay>
    <quoteDay>
      <date>2018-02-23</date>
      <close>1577,11</close>
    </quoteDay>
    <quoteDay>
      <date>2018-02-22</date>
      <close>1565,5</close>
    </quoteDay>
</root>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php                                
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            $id = -1;
            $total[] = 0;

            foreach ($xml->root as $root) {                    
                foreach ($root->quoteDay as $quoteDay) {
                    $id ++;
                    $total[] += $root->quoteDay[$id]->close;                        
                    $close = number_format(round($quoteDay->close,0));     
                    echo $quoteDay->date; echo $close; echo $total[$id+1];  
                }
            }
    ?>
```

So, for each quoteDay, I would like to return the date, close and a moving average.

Date 2018-02-26 would return the mean of "close" for 2018-02-26 and 2018-02-23 = (1586,96+1577,11)/2.

Mean for 2018-02-23 would return (1577,11+1565,5)/2.

I've, as you can see, tried to sum a cumulative total sum for each element, but for some reason I can't understand it won't work.

How can I accomplish calculating a moving average for the elements?

Comment: What is the mean for `2018-02-22`? `1565,5 + ? / 2` ?

Comment: I've got more elements than I posted, but that's a fair input, since the last element won't return any mean. I will have to put an if-statement to check if there is previous element. @Mikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your result you need to do a couple of things:

- `simplexml_load_file()` already gives you the root, so there's no need for your first loop
- The `$total` array is not necessary
- Your XML has `,` as decimal separators, but PHP uses `.`, so you need to replace them in order to do math and not lose the decimals (here I cast to `float` which can make you lose precision, look into [`bcmath`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) to avoid that)
- I assume that for the first day, when there's no previous, the moving average is the day's value

So, your code would look like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("a.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$id = 0;
foreach ($xml->quoteDay as $quoteDay) {
    echo "Moving average for ".$quoteDay->date.":".PHP_EOL;
    $current = (float) str_replace(",", ".", $quoteDay->close);
    $previous = $xml->quoteDay[$id + 1]
        ? (float) str_replace(",", ".", $xml->quoteDay[$id + 1]->close)
        : $current;
    $movingMean = ($current + $previous) / 2;
    echo $movingMean.PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $id++;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jmges)

*Result*

> Moving average for 2018-02-26:
>   1582.035
>
> Moving average for 2018-02-23:
>   1571.305
>
> Moving average for 2018-02-22:
>   1565.5

To generalize it to `$daysInMovingMean` days, use a `for` loop to get the days up to the days needed, stopping earlier if necessary (i.e. no more days left):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("a.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$id = 0;
$daysInMovingMean = 3;
foreach ($xml->quoteDay as $quoteDay) {
    echo "Moving average for ".$quoteDay->date.":".PHP_EOL;
    $sum = 0;
    for ($days = 0; $days < $daysInMovingMean; $days++) { 
        if (!$xml->quoteDay[$id + $days]) break;
        $sum += (float) str_replace(",", ".", $xml->quoteDay[$id + $days]->close);
    }
    $sumovingMean = $sum / $days;
    echo $sumovingMean.PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $id++;
}
```

Notice that in this example you get the same results as before if you set `$daysInMovingMean = 2;`

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VGhhQ)

Comment: Thank you! Can you answer aswell if it's possible for the $previous variable to append a range of elements? Like $previous = $xml->quoteDay[range($id, $id +2)].